# xcode 4.2 doesn't show errors at build

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

xcode 4.2 build 4D177b doesn't show error in the issue navigator. When I build the app it pops up the build failed, but in the issue navigator the reason doesn't appear. I'm attaching a screenshot about the problem. How can I see the errors?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I found the answer: I had to search for the bug manually, and after that, I had to click on the red error icon at the beginning of the line.

Comment: You should write up your answer as an answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: when the error won't show on the Issue Navigator could be because there is something written in the filter (the search text field on the bottom of the pane) of the Issue navigate itself.

Answer (score 0):

i've had issues where the workspace is invalid or corrupt due to pods needing update. if you've switched to a different source control branch recently and pods have changed, and your pods configuration expects a pod that hasn't been installed yet, sometimes it won't display the errors for your main target. try pod install to make sure the workspace, which is managed by cocoapods, is current.